# JSF validateLength question

Tags: validation, jsf

I have a input field with validation to validate the max and min length

```
<h:inputText id="LABEL_ID" styleClass="textboxsmall" value="#{sampleDatatableBean.accessionLabelId}" maxlength="5">
    <f:validateLength minimum="4" maximum="5" />
</h:inputText>
<br/><h:message id="LABEL_ID_MSG" styleClass="errorMessage" for="LABEL_ID" />
```

It validates but I get the below message:

> "Value is less than allowable minimum of {0}"

Shouldn't `{0}` be replaced by value from minimum? Not sure why its not picking up the value. Any ideas?

```
Version info:
myfaces-api-1.1.5.jar:
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver 
Created-By: Apache Maven 
Built-By: mrmaven 
Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_11 
Implementation-Title: API 
Implementation-Version: 1.1.6-SNAPSHOT 
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache.myfaces.core 
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation 

myfaces-impl-1.1.5.jar:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: mrmaven
Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_11
Implementation-Title: Impl
Implementation-Version: 1.1.6-SNAPSHOT
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.apache.myfaces.core
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
```

AppServer:jboss-4.0.5.GA

Works for

```
<f:validateLongRange   minimum="100"   maximum="999" />
```

---

**FIXED**
Seems to work after adding the _detail in the ErrorMessages_en.properties file.

```
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM_detail = Value is longer than allowable 
maximum of {0} characters.
```

Comment: I recall this issue, but I don't recall the solution anymore. Can you please post which JSF impl/version/build you're using? Extract the jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl jar, check the manifest file, it contains exact version information. Also, which appserver are you using? Also, how about the other messages, are they evaluating fine?

Comment: Well, look like a bug in MyFaces. Can't reproduce this with Mojarra. Try upgrading MyFaces or replacing by Mojarra.

Comment: I just checked jboss-4.0.5.GA has a Servlet Spec 2.4 and JSP 2.0; MyFaces update req. -JSF 1.2 requires java 1.5 or later, JSP 2.1, JSTL 1.2 and a Java Servlet 2.5 implementation.: Do you think it would cause issues if I just updated the jars without updating the server to required specification?

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. Good luck with the problem.

Comment: FIXED Seems to work after adding the "javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM_detail" in the ErrorMessages_en.properties file.

Comment: As per your update: in other words: MyFaces uses their own message keys? That's not very nice of them. By the way, you are eligible to post this as an **answer** and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED Seems to work after adding the "javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM_detail" in the ErrorMessages_en.properties file.