# how to solve f:validateLength error message in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have ui:repeat  when i get minSize and maxSize i got error

```
j_idt59:2:string: Validation Error: Length is greater than allowable maximum of '0'
```

i tried to print values on screen the output is true min is 0 and max is 20
but when i set in f:validateLength  i got error message

this my code

```
<p:inputText required="#{fileds.required == true? true : false}"
        id="string" requiredMessage="#{language.messageErrorRequied.value}"
        value="#{layoutComponentView.typeFiledsMap[fileds.code.concat(language.lang)]}">
      <f:validateLength minimum="#{fileds.minSize}" maximum="#{fileds.maxSize}" />
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: This can be regarding configuration value. Did you refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804934/jsf-validatelength-question] ?

Comment: @vebbie: I don't think it is related to that. Most likely bean scope/creation issue in code not visible. OP: please create a [mcve] and please post version info

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682196/using-validator-with-a-variable-attribute-in-uirepeat